# Can I save my PowerBI Visualizations as Data Table?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I made a simple table from the data set I had. I obtained summary information by using features such as count in the table. Using this summary data, I want to get another graph (like a Pie chart). Is there a way to use the data I produce in this table as a data source? For example, can I save this data as a data Table?
I can't do it by exporting the data because my data comes live with DirectQuery.
Thanks for your help...

Comment: Have you tried copying your table visual and pasting, then with the new copy selected, select Pie chart.